# Block user from connecting MiFi units to computers

Tags: windows, group-policy

The scenario: a user connects a MiFi device to a computer on the Windows Domain network to charge it. This MiFi acted as a network interface and the computer's network traffic started going out through the MiFi.

This is obviously not wanted as this bypasses our network security.

How can I prevent such a situation to occur (other than telling users to not do that... since they do it anyway).

Ideally, users would not be permitted to connect any new network devices (could be MiFi, a 3/4G USB dongle, even a USB-Network adapter). It should require an Administrator logon. But USB storage devices should still work (I have policies in place for some users to get Read/Write and some Read-only).

Comment: Use Group Policy to block/restrict USB devices.

Comment: @joeqwerty - but I want to keep USB Storage device working... maybe I'm misunderstanding the meaning of the policy or missing the right one...

Comment: No, I misunderstood those GP settings. My apologies.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/807188/126632

Comment: @MichaelHampton - wow, somehow didn't find this one in my search! Thanks. Going to try this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. Run gpedit.msc
2. In the *Group Policy* window navigate to *User Configuration* > *Administration Templates* > *Network* > *Network Connections* > *Prohibit access to properties of a LAN connection*
3. Enable this option and apply changes.

Comment: Link-only answers are not a good idea because the content you linked to can easily disappear.  Can you make this answer stand on its own?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers